# Как изменить Label в окне чужой программы?

Tags: delphi

Есть чужая программа написанная на Delphi, в которой нужно изменить текст на label. От программы имеется только её .dfm файл, то есть известно о названия компонентов. Как поменять текст у этой программы с помощью другой?

То есть я запуская программу потом запускаю свою программу, и моя уже ищет findwindow и с помощью sendmessage должна как-то изменить этот текст.

Не предлагайте изменять dfm файл, ничего остального для перекомпиляции все равно нету. Exe программы также никак нельзя изменять, она перестаёт работать и пишет что взломана.

Comment: Если знаете, уточните пожалуйста в вопросе (кнопка "править") версию Делфи в которой собрано чужое приложение и операционку, и какой там использован фреймворк, классический VCL или новый мультиплатформенный FMX? По возможности, приложите скриншот приложения.

Comment: Если вы знаете про findwindow и sendmessage, то в чем проблема?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов в том что лейбл не оконный элемент и ему нельзя отправить сообщение?

Comment: Собственно, в чем смысл изменять текст в `TLabel`? Просто "для фана"? Или вывести что-то полезное? Если программка маленькая, то можно создать win-контрол поверх этого `TLabel` и вывести свой текст (я так понимаю, вывести надо одноразово). Да, скриншот бы не помешал, а то непонятно, что там за лейбл, да и лейбл ли вообще.

Comment: Не "для фана", а для перевода программы.

Comment: `TLabel` - невизуальный компонент, поэтому с помощью `FindWindow()` управлять им не получится. Нужно либо научиться корректно редактировать ресурсы *.dfm в исполняемом файле (это возможно, иначе как бы работали программы типа "Restorator" и "Resource Hacker"?), либо применять хакерские методы, чтобы извне получить доступ к объекту TForm и его методам, а через них - к интересующему объекту TLabel

Comment: оговорился в предыдущем комментарии: хотел сказать, что `TLabel` не является наследником `TWinControl`, т.е. не имеет хэндла HWND из Win32 API. Потому и управлять им через функции Win32 API не выйдет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В программах, написанных на Delphi с применением VCL, dfm-файлы в неизменном виде хранятся в ресурсах. Проще всего распаковать exe при помощи редактора ресурсов, изменить dfm-файл и упаковать обратно.

**UPD**
Учитывая дополнение про защиту exe от редактирования, в данном случае мой ответ не подходит. Но удалять не буду, вдруг кому-то с подобной проблемой пригодится.

Comment: +1, Отличный вариант, если текст нужно изменить однократно на статику/хардкод. А если новый текст короче, то можно и просто отредактировать EXE заменив строку на новую равной длины (дополнив, к примеру, пробелами)

Comment: А если не влезет новый текст? :) И не факт что текст Ascii, может и скорее всего utf16

Comment: @NewView, ANSI там или UTF-16 зависит от версии VCL. Если UTF-16, то используются HEX-коды символов. Это знает любой делфист, хоть раз отрывавший dfm-файл (ALT+F12)

Comment: Exe программы не как нельзя изменять она перестаёт работать и пишет что она взломана

Comment: @AimonZ., лучше бы это указали в вопросе, чем невнятный абзац про dfm

Comment: Добавил это в вопрос за ТС. Комент можно удалить.